# Determining the equation of state when given thermodynamic relations

Tags: thermodynamics, equation-of-state

> Empirical observations of a thermodynamic system have shown that:
>
> $$\begin{align}C_{\mathrm m,V} &\neq C_{\mathrm m,V}(T) \\[6pt]
> \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V_\mathrm m}\right)_{T} &= f(V_\mathrm m) \\[6pt]
> \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}\right)_{V} &= g(V_\mathrm m) \end{align}$$
>
> where $f$ and $g$ are functions of the molar volume, $V_\mathrm m$. Determine the state equation.

How can I solve this problem?